# Jquery UI datepicker not working with handsontable

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, handsontable

I have a page with handsontable and the jquery UI datapicker component ?

By themselves, they work fine.
Jquery UI datepicker, http://jsfiddle.net/7Bvap/355/

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
```

Handsontable , http://jsfiddle.net/ngpxZ/

But when I put them together, 
the datepicker doesnt work (as in the calendar doesnt pop out)
http://jsfiddle.net/cuj3V/

I found a similar problem here,
https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/498 
**For page with handsontable as workaround I'm reloading jquery ui css after handson table css and works fine.**

So I placed the handsontable.css before the jqueryui.css. But still no avail. Anyone can help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a problem with the jsFiddle including the scripts/styles in the css section. You should not need to use the CSS section to include external files. Use the "External Resources" menu instead

[image: jsFiddle External resources]

```
external resources
```

[Datepicker and handsontable jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/erupenkman/9pn5X/)